# Android, Is it possible to format textview like System.out.format("%02d", n);?

Tags: android, textview, format

I have a table with different columns. instead of creating text view for each item i want to have one textview for each row. i want to add each item one by one to row string. because some items may have 1 digit and some others may have two digits, i want to format it.

in Java we do something like:

```
intn = 7;
System.out.format("%0d", n);      //  -->  "07"
```

is it possible do same way with textview? if yes how to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, refer to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
String text = String.format("%0d", n);
textView.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 11):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Formatting strings

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>

Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages), username, mailCount);
```

Comment: [getString(int, Object...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...)) is more convenient.

Comment: yes, but here i just put the code that was on the link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a format string in resource file, :

```
<string name="message">Test: %d, %s</string>
```

then call (you can use unlimited number of arguments):

```
String str = context.getResources().getString(R.string.message, 100, "hello" );
```