# How to add spaces in a Firebase Database value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently having a problem. In my database one of the values ​​is displayed like this:

**account balance: "1000000"**

And I would like something like this:

**account balance: "1 000 000"**

I would like to know how to put spaces so that we can read more easily if it's thousands, millions ect..

**Can this be done automatically on the Firebase side?**

Comment: I think Frank is right about his suggestions, but if you wanted to you could use **cloud functions** to change the data automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase database, console, and SDK have no functionality built in to modify your data. That's typically task that is left to your application code. For example: [How to display formatted amounts in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343522/how-to-display-formatted-amounts-in-textview)

I'd also recommend storing the values as numbers instead of (as you now show in your question) as strings. Storing the numeric values as a numeric type makes it easier to manipulate them and sort on them.